# GCP Load Balancer, SSL FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've created a compute VM, then went though the steps 2 days ago to attached my Google purchased Domain, added Load Balancer, Instance Group, and SSL.  I followed these instructions.  The Status of Domain is Failed not Visible.  Anyone have any tips/tricks on what could have went wrong?

[image]

Comment: The error FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE[1] indicates that certificate provisioning failed for a domain because of a problem with DNS or the load balancing configuration. Make sure that DNS is configured so that the certificate's domain resolves to the IP address of the load balancer.
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting#domain-status

Comment: Kindly check if your A record from your DNS records reflect the same IP address as the frontend IP address of your Load Balancer. Aside from checking the DNS records, you may also do a dig by entering your domain here[1]. Entering your domain name should translate to the front end IP of your Load Balancer.

[1]: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/

Answer (score 0):

`FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE` means that the Certificate provisioning hasn't completed for the domain. The reason is listed below and the workarounds can also be found in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting#domain-status:%7E:text=ACTIVE%20as%20well.-,FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE,-Certificate%20provisioning%20hasn%27t) so kindly check them.

- The domain's DNS record doesn't resolve to the Front End IP address of the Google Cloud load balancer.
- Newly updated DNS A and AAAA records can take a significant amount of time to be fully propagated. Sometimes propagation across the internet takes up to 72 hours worldwide, although it typically takes a few hours. The domain status continues to be FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE until propagation is complete.
- The SSL certificate isn't attached to the load balancer's target proxy.
- The frontend ports for the global forwarding rule do not include port 443 for an external SSL proxy load balancer.